# pyspark, aggregations results in an error

Tags: pyspark

I can print dataframe fine before aggregation

```
(Pdb) df_interesting.printSchema()
root
 |-- userId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- screen_index: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- type: string (nullable = true)
 |-- time_delta: float (nullable = true)
 |-- app_open_index: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- timestamp: timestamp (nullable = true)

(pdb) df_interesting.show(n=2)

+------+------------+------+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|userId|screen_index|  type|time_delta|app_open_index|           timestamp|
+------+------------+------+----------+--------------+--------------------+
|214431|           7|screen|      60.0|            13|2020-07-31 07:52:...|
|398910|           3|screen|      60.0|             2|2020-07-29 11:43:...|
+------+------------+------+----------+--------------+--------------------+
```

However, after aggregation, show() results in an error..

```
(Pdb) df_interesting.groupBy('app_open_index').agg(F.max("screen_index").alias("max_screen_index")).show(n=2)
[Stage 1:>                                                                   (0 + 2) / 2]20/08/13 18:07:26 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 1.0 (TID 1)
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value (Buffer()) of the type (scala.collection.convert.Wrappers.JListWrapper) cannot be converted to the string type
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:290)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StringConverter$.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:285)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:248)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$StructConverter.toCatalystImpl(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:238)
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.CatalystTypeConverters$CatalystTypeConverter.toCatalyst(CatalystTypeConverters.scala:103)
```

- Edit

I tried to single out the column, and here's some progress

```
(Pdb) df_interesting = df_interesting.select(col('data.userId').alias('userId'))
(Pdb) df_interesting.count()
[Stage 0:>                                                                   (0 + 2) / 2]20/08/13 18:59:12 ERROR Executor: Exception in task 1.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 1)
org.elasticsearch.hadoop.rest.EsHadoopParsingException: org.elasticsearch.hadoop.EsHadoopIllegalStateException: Field 'data.properties.priceObj' not found; typically this occurs \
with arrays which are not mapped as single value
```

Comment: `show()` does not go through whole data, and even if it prints results for `show()`, it does not mean everything is printable. Try for example `count()` and see if that works in the first place. I would even try persisting to make sure ;)

Comment: I think you are spot on. I think there's some garbage data in some of rows.. How do I find out what that data look like (which column is buggy) when I can't `show` ?

Comment: can you persist() your data set and count() it? Or it's too big? Also in this specific case, I would investigate `screen_index` column. My fist guess is that Spark has difficulty finding `max` for some values. Is it possible that some  entities are `None`?

Comment: I have filter('screen_index is not NULL') so it's not.. how does persist() help? I would If it helps by slicing data..

Comment: When you persist, it has to go through all rows, and if there is any crap, it complains that it does not match the schema, etc. Slicing might not work if you are not lucky. For instance if schema of one slice is not the same as that of another slice, each slice will be persisted perfectly, but aggregated would not!

Comment: @AlaTarighati Actually, there are documents that are missing the column altogether, is there a way to filter those data out?

Comment: What if you first `select()` those two columns of interest?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that and found weird .. some other column is causing an error. I added the error in the op

Comment: I eliminated fields by setting session.read.include , I'd like to thank you for help.. i could accept if you make an answer..  @AlaTarighati

Comment: Good to hear that it worked out :)